# Gb with polychord next to it2/#4?

Tags: chords, chord-theory, sheet-music

So, I'm arranging a medly and I'm very new to music, so sorry if this is common knowledge but... I found this chord

[image]

I understand it means to add 2 and #4 but, I don't know what it is called. If anyone could tell me what the fraction or whatever it is on the side is called that would be much appreciated.

Also, can I use it in Musescore 3?

Thanks! Have a great day!

Comment: isn't it just called "G Flat Two Sharp Four"?

Comment: What do you mean precisely by "I found this chord"? Did you find it on a lead sheet, or similar? Certainly, that symbol is not common. It would be interesting if you can share your source. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a G♭ triad with added 2 (A♭) and sharpened 4th (C♮).

(This is completely independent of any key signature - just like a C major triad is always C, E and G (all naturals) whatever the prevailing key signature.)

It's not a chord symbol you'll often see, and yes, I'd expect the 4 to be written above the 2.  But it's quite clear.  You're being told to play G♭, A♭, B♭, C♮ and D♭.   The first half of a G♭ Lydian scale.

Yes, you can do stacked chord extensions in Musescore.  It seems tricky though!  See if you can make head or tail of this:
https://musescore.org/en/node/274113

(Extended chord symbols work a bit differently to figured bass.  In figured bass 2 and 4 would imply a third inversion dominant 7th chord.  And it's not a Polychord. That means something quite different.  I won't go into it here, but you can look it up.)

Answer (score -1):

The numbers on the side are the usually called "figures" and stem from the practice of "figured bass" (it has other names) where a bass note is written and numbers indicate the notes played above the given note. Here the Gb means (as mentioned by the OP), a G flat chord; the 2 and #4 should mean add the second above the Gb and the sharpened fourth. Sans key signature, I'm not sure what these two notes are (some flavor of A and C). I've usually seen this written with the 4 above the 2 but it's unambiguous as shown.

It's really a "tone-cluster"; in this case, 5 consecutive notes played together. It may have a chordal name but its use is more important than the name.

Comment: Chord Symbols may look a bit like Figured Bass, but they work rather differently.   And the key signature makes no difference.  The notes implied by a Chord Symbol are absolute.